# Problems with multiple jquery .ajax function calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a function that I'm calling that validates a recaptcha, and then depending on whether that validates successfully, sends out an email.  I am validating the recaptcha using a jquery .ajax function, and upon successful validation uses another jquery .ajax function to send the email.

Here is the javascript:

```
function validateCaptcha(){
var isValid = $('#es_contact_form').valid();
var esform = $('#es_contact_form').serialize();
var html = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "scripts/ajax.recaptcha.php",
data: esform,
async: false
}).responseText;

if(isValid)
{
   if(html == "success")
   {
        //alert("Captcha and form are valid");
    //return true;
    var esform2 = $('#es_contact_form').serialize();
    var response = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/ajax.email.php",
    data: esform2,
    async: false
    }).responseText2;
    if(response=="success")
    {
    alert('mail successfully sent');
                    return true;
                }else{
                    alert('mail not sent, please try again');
                    Recaptcha.reload();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Form valid, captcha bogus');
                $("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again");
                Recaptcha.reload();
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            if(html == "success")
            {
                //alert("Captcha's good, but the form aint!");
                Recaptcha.reload();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //alert('Form invalid, captcha bogus...can you do anything right?');
                $("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again");
                Recaptcha.reload();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the serverside code for the script where I am getting the 500 server error:

```
<?php

$yourName = 'ES';
$yourEmail = 'rob@domain.com';
$yourSubject = 'ES: contact form';
$referringPage = 'es.domain.com';



function cleanPosUrl ($str) {
$nStr = $str;
$nStr = str_replace("**am**","&",$nStr);
$nStr = str_replace("**pl**","+",$nStr);
$nStr = str_replace("**eq**","=",$nStr);
return stripslashes($nStr);
}
if ( isset($_POST) ) {
$to = $yourEmail;
$subject = $yourSubject;
$message = cleanPosUrl($_POST['name'])."\r\n\n";
$message .= cleanPosUrl($_POST['remail'])."\r\n\n";
$message .= cleanPosUrl($_POST['phone'])."\r\n\n";
$message .= cleanPosUrl($_POST['comments']);
$headers = "From: ".cleanPosUrl($_POST['name'])." <".cleanPosUrl($_POST['remail']).">\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: '.$yourName.' <'.$yourEmail.'>'."\r\n";
$mailit = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

    if ( $mailit )
    { ?>success<? }
    else
    { die ("The mail wasn't sent"); }
}
?>
```

Both ajax.recaptcha.php and ajax.email.php pull from the post and then return "success" if they are successful.

The ajax.recaptcha.php is working fine. But when it gets to the ajax.email.php script, I keep getting a 500 server error in Firebug.

Does anyone have a clue as to why one would work and not the other?  The scripts are both in the same folder on the same server, so I can't see why this isn't working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 500 error means server-side error. Look at your php script for the one that is failing.

Comment: I updated the post to show the php script that is getting the 500 server error, hopefully this will help.

Comment: @KevinB that wouldn't be about the code, if you have a syntaxerror you would get THAT back from the ajax call, not a 500 error.

Comment: @11684 - If the server is responding with 500, it is an internal server error. If it responded with 200 or 0, then it would more than likely be a js error. As far as what you get back from the server, that differs per setup.

Comment: then he has to make an AJAX call to a PHP file with a syntaxerror, and see what comes back. Then we know if it is a PHP syntaxerror or not. Or he could try to go to the page  with the browser and POST stuff with a normal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra } in the code.. you should get rid of } right after

```
$mailit = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I completely agree with jugnu, For better debugging in such case you should try using static values to send email. (instead of POST[]).

Comment: Wow...TGIF. Thanks for the second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

in your php script,

try var_dum($_POST) in ur if condition where you checking params, possible error causing due to this,

see wot you see after that var_dump, if u see any problem then change you condition with **$_GET** or **$_REQUEST**